# How does one install and use PyPy on a Mac correctly?

Tags: macos, python-3.x, installation, pypy

I have installed PyPy for mac from [here](http://pypy.org/download.html) and I have read the ReadMe and all that (which wasn't too useful to me).

But now I am wondering how exactly do you use it. I learn really well from examples and it turns out there aren't many examples out there for Macs.

So can someone explain the steps of properly installing PyPy and building code with PyPy?

Optional: How do you use it outside of the terminal in applets?

Answer (score 4):

Using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

```
brew install pypy
```

or

```
brew install pypy3
```

Answer (score 0):

To use pypy best I would suggest using it via a virtualenv. Just run virtualenv -p  and you can work having pypy as "python". If you never used virtualenvs before, I strongly suggest reading about them, whether you're using pypy or not.

As for applets - I have absolutely no clue, but I would expect you just need to prefix them with #!/usr/bin/env pypy or something.